# What is the difference between an installed scope, before and after the first reboot?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, scopes

I'm playing around with Ubuntu touch scopes, but I have one strange problem. When I create a scope (this is also true for the example scopes: new project -> Unity Scope (current) -> Qtscope using HTTP+...) and I install it on a device, it works nice.

But, when I reboot the device, the scope don't work anymore. When I start a self-created scope (after reboot), the hole scope-engine crashes. When I reinstall the scope before starting it and after a reboot, it works fine (until next reboot).

Where do I start, to find out what's going wrong? What is the difference between an installed scope, before and after the first reboot?

ps: I'm using Qt-creator with Ubuntu-SDK to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the difference, but my problem is solved by reïnstalling the ubuntu-sdk. Strange because I used a fresh install.